# Javascript Email Validation With Special Requirements

Tags: javascript

I'm asked to write a JS code to validate email with these conditions:

> Email: contains a valid email address (an email address is considered valid if it has the form `[name]@[domain]; [name]` consists of letters `(a to z, both lower and upper cases)`, digits, and dots; however, two dots cannot be positioned next to each other and dots cannot be located at the beginning or at the end of `[name]`; the length of `[name]` is at least 3; `[domain]` consists of letters, digits, and dots too; however, there should be at least one dot in [domain]; similar to `[name]`, two dots cannot be positioned next to each other and dots cannot be located at the beginning or at the end of `[domain]`; finally, the part of `[domain]` after the last dot contains only letters and has a minimum length of 2 and a maximum length of 5; examples of valid email addresses: `123@1.me, 1.2.3@domain.name, this.is.my.email@sub.sub.123.main; examples of invalid email addresses: .dot.at.the.beginning@test.com, name@domainnamewithoutdot, another@last.part.consists.num.b3r, there.is space@domain.name).`

I have tried to research for different regexs and was able to come up with this one:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]{3,}+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,5}$/
```

It doesn't meet the requirement. I am still very new to JS and my teacher isn't too good at teaching either. So I would really appreciate some suggestions/hints to what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one:

```js
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/
```

Comment: It matches all valid examples and does not match all invalid examples.